# Are all favicon sizes fetched from the server?

Tags: favicon

If I specify different image sizes for favicon PNGs like so:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="24x24" href="/favicon-24px.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32px.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="48x48" href="/favicon-48px.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="64x64" href="/favicon-64px.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="256x256" href="/favicon-256px.png" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="512x512" href="/favicon-512px.png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
```

Does every one of these files get fetched?

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/:

> How do these PNG-favicon-compatible browsers determine which favicon
> should be used? Firefox and Safari will use the favicon that comes
> last. Chrome for Mac will use whichever favicon is ICO formatted,
> otherwise the 32×32 favicon. Chrome for Windows will use the favicon
> that comes first if it is 16×16, otherwise the ICO. If none of the
> aforementioned options are available, both Chromes will use whichever
> favicon comes first, exactly the opposite of Firefox and Safari.
> Indeed, Chrome for Mac will ignore the 16×16 favicon and use the 32×32
> version if only to scale it back down to 16×16 on non-retina devices.
> Opera, not wanting to take sides, will choose from any of the
> available icons at complete random. I love that Opera does this.
>
> And that’s just the beginning. Now it’s time to learn about the
> Internet Explorer caveats.
>
> While IE8-10 will display
> the favicon on first load of the page, IE7 will skip the first load
> and display the favicon during repeat visits. Worse yet, IE6 will only
> display the favicon once the site has been bookmarked and reopened in
> the browser. IE6 will also drop the favicon whenever the browser cache
> is cleared, and it will not display the favicon again until the site
> is either re-bookmarked, or the favicon is somehow reloaded. If IE6
> and favicons mean a lot to you, you can force this reload with a
> little JavaScript snippet, preferably wrapped in a conditional
> comment.
>
> ```
> <!-- I "support" IE6 -->
> <!--[if IE 6]><script>(new Image).src="path/to/favicon.ico"</script><![endif]-->
> ```

Comment: If anyone can provide more specifics (as described above), please do. I would rather award the bounty to someone else.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#rel-icon), the most appropriate icon will be used. So there is no a need to fetch something that has no use.

> If multiple icons are provided, the user agent must select the most appropriate icon according to the type, media, and sizes attributes.

Comment: The spec only says that it will decide which to use.  Whether it fetches is just an assumption though.

Comment: And don't count on the most appropriate icon being fetched. Firefox seems to just get the largest one and then scales it down. Internet Explorer doesn't seem to support PNG files at all.

Comment: Well, I agree, if there's no explicit information on the specification, so it's likely to vary from browser to browser, as the browser could just download the one to use, or download all to cache and use on future (the least presumable). Anyway, just reading some access logs will answer good part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly, I observed that some browsers are loading all PNG favicons, not only the most suitable one:

- Chrome on Windows
- Chrome on Android
- Firefox on Windows

I didn't tested other settings, like Firefox on Android.

More about the ["all favicons are loaded" issue](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#troubleshootings).

Answer (score -1):

The browser will get only one file, if any.